# Invalid scalar projection in foreach

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

Hi I have a pig script like this. When doing foreach statement it throws invalid scalar projection error.Here is my code.

```
a = load 'file' using PigStorage(':');
b = group a by ($1, $7, $11);
c = foreach b generate flatten(group), COUNT(a) as (cnt: int);
d = filter c by cnt>1;
e = foreach d generate flatten(a) ;
```

The error is shown below

```
<line 6, column 31> Invalid scalar projection: a : A column needs to be projected from a relation for it to be used as a scalar
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I posted this code as an answer yesterday. If you don't get any duplicate rows after grouping by `$1, $7, $11`, your relation `d` will be empty and hence when you will try to implement relation `e`, you will get this error.

Comment: Thanks philan...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because, 'a' doesn's exists in the 'd' relation schema.

describe the 'd' schema, you get:
d: {bytearray,bytearray,bytearray, cnt: int} in which 'a' doesn't exists.

In the script, C relation is formed, by Projection of flattening the group field and Number of elements of a, a is not included in the relation C.